# Переопределение private в дочернем классе (PHP)

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

Не знаю, как точнее озаглавить проблему, но суть в следующем:
В родительском классе я описал три свойства с разными областями видимости (public, protected, private).
В дочернем классе я пытаюсь переопределить эти три свойства.
Затем, из дочернего класса я вызываю унаследованный метод, который выводит все три свойства.
На выходе я получаю измененные свойства public и protected, однако private выводит родительский.
Точно так же происходит, если вместо свойств использовать методы public protected private.

Однако, при переопределении метода (выводящего значения свойств) в дочернем классе, на выходе я получаю все три измененных свойства.

Почему при переопределении метода вывод правильный, а при его наследовании - нет?

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    function Foo()
    {
        echo $this->public . " " . $this->protected . " " . $this->private;
    }
    public $public = "public";
    protected $protected = "protected";
    private $private = "private";
}

class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public $public = "New_public";
    protected $protected = "New_protected";
    private $private = "New_private";   
}

(new NewClass())->Foo(); //Выводит New_public New_Protected private
?>
```

Comment: Выложите код текстом пожалуйста, а не картинкой.

Comment: Я не специалист в `php`, но так как знаком с `ооп` могу предположить что он ищет указанное свойство `private`, но так как не находит его в текущем классе- обращается к базовому классу. Вот и получаете `"private"` из базового класса.

Comment: @Anamnian извиняюсь, вставил неверный участок кода, сейчас исправил. При таком раскладе все равно private на выходе.

Comment: Странное поведение в `php`. Ваш код переведенный в `C#` выдает свойства родителя, если вызывать метод `Foo` для ребенка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну собсна вы и столкнулись с тем, зачем нужен `private`. Смысл в том что `private` - родителя не доступен для ребенка и наоборот.

`Private` может вызвать только сам класс, в котором он указан.

В вашем случае, если не трогать `MyClass`. А изменить `NewClass` на:

```
class NewClass extends MyClass {
    public $public = "New_public";
    protected $protected = "New_protected";
    //private $private = "New_private";
    function Foo() {
        echo $this->public . " " . $this->protected . " " . $this->private;
    }
}
```

Вы можете увидеть, что родительский `private` вы не получите. Однако убрав комментарии `//` с `private` вы его получите в ответе.

Дело в том что у них разные области видимости:

```
object(NewClass) {
    ["$public"]                     => "New_public"
    ["$protected":protected]        => "New_protected"
    ["$private":"NewClass":private] => "New_private"
    ["$private":"MyClass":private]  => "private"
}
```

Т.к. вы вызываете `Foo()` из родителя, в его области видимости отсутствует `private $private = "New_private";`, однако есть свой, поэтому и берет.

Если переопределить `Foo()` в ребенке, то теперь `Foo()` будет работать с областью видимости ребенка, и приватные методы родителя - будут недоступны.

Как-то так...

Comment: Спасибо, кажется, разобрался, после того, как увидел область видимости для `private`

Comment: @vault_boy обращайтесь ;)

Answer (score 1):

Наткнулся случайно на форум, где еще в 2015 году обсуждали этот вопрос. Здесь мне стало понятно, почему вообще приватное свойство наследуется и почему к нему можно обращаться.

https://php.ru/forum/threads/oop-nasledovanie-private-svojstv.51487/#post-411494